# Limit cycle of ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limit-cycles

I have problems with the following exercise. Prove that the system
\begin{align*}
    \dot{x} &= x(x^2+y^2-2x-3) - y\\
    \dot{y} &= y(x^2+y^2-2x-3) + x
\end{align*}
has a cycle limit.

My attempt: I think I have to apply Poncaire-Bendixon Theorem. First, I changed the system to polar coordinate, then I have

\begin{align*}
    \dot{r} &= (r^2-2r \cos\theta-3)r\\
\end{align*}

From this point, I noticed that if $r>3$, then
$$\dot{r}>0.$$
But for $r<1$
$$\dot{r} < 0.$$
Then, I guess I have a cycle limit in $1<r<3$ for Poncaire-Bendixon theorem. But I think this is only an heuristic way to do the exercise. There exist other approach?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you have typos in the inequalities for $\dot r$. But otherwise, if you prove now that there is no equilibrium point in the region where the trajectory is trapped, then you will have proven that the system exhibits a limit cycle.